# icalendar and phpmailer.php

Tags: php, phpmailer, icalendar

i am trying to send icalendar to the users, so that they can open these ics files in outlook and save the appointment. mailer i am using is 'phpmailer.php'.

problem is that it sends ical format as html in message body. Here is my code

```
$text="
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:1.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CATEGORIES:MEETING
STATUS:TENTATIVE
DTSTART:".$startDateTime."
DTEND:".$endDateTime."
SUMMARY:Interview for the candidate".$cname."
DESCRIPTION:".$message."
CLASS:PRIVATE
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR";

$mail->SetFrom('xxxxxx@yahoo.com', 'xxxx');
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com";

$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'xxxxxxxx@yahoo.com';
$mail->Password = 'xxxxx';


$mail->AddAddress($addresses[$i]);
$mail->Subject    = "Interview schedule of Candidate";

    $headers = "From: Sender\n";
        $headers .= "Reply-To: xxxxxx@yahoo.com\n";
        $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/calendar; method=REQUEST; charset=utf-8\n";
        $headers .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n";
        $headers .= "Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage\n";
$mail->Body=$body;

if(!$mail->Send($headers,$body)) 
{
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} 
else 
{
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Please let me know what is wrong with my code.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you send it as an attachment?

Comment: thanks @Nelson i did that with attachment :)

Comment: @Nelson do you have any idea how can I achieve the same with zend_mail. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17646307/sending-ical-through-zend-mail)

Comment: I don't see where you use the variable $text ...

Comment: Which version of phpMailer are you using? Because in 5.2.6+ the send method doesn't take any parameters.

Comment: @GuillaumeBois this thread is 3 years old. i guess it was something around 3.0 version. Well i appreciate you suggested something good which might help other users too. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also have tried:

```
$mail->IsHTML(FALSE);
```

Answer (score 5):

The following solution worked for me:

```
$mail->Subject = $name;
$mail->Body = $description; 
$mail->AltBody = $body; // in your case once more the $text string
$mail->Ical = $message; // ical format, in your case $text string
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution Works for me. without attachemnt

```
$mail->AddStringAttachment("my_content_here", "meeting.ics", "7bit", "text/calendar; charset=utf-8; method=REQUEST");
```