# How to add message body in PHP mailer?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I wanna add a message text into my mail body but couldn't make it. When I add $mail->Body="Blablabla" into my code it doesn't read the variable. 
Do I have to use another header? Some resources would be great

EDİT: when i write this:

```
   $content = '<div style="background: #eee; padding: 10px; font-size: 14px">Bu bir test e-posta\'dır..</div>';
    $mail->MsgHTML($content);
```

before `$mail->Body = $ical;`there is no calendar but it prints the string. But if i put the code after that it prints all ical codes.

```
    $venue = $place1;
    $start = $tarih_duzen;
    $start_time = $rz_baslama_saat;
    $end = $tarih_duzen_bit;
    $end_time = $rz_bit_saat;
    $status = 'TENTATIVE';
    $sequence = 0;
    $event_id = 1234;
    //$event['description'] = "<table border=1><tr><td>qqqq</td></tr><table>";

    //PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Host = '127.0.0.1';  // Specify main and backup server
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username = 'someuser';                            // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = 'somepassword';
    $mail->Port = 25;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom( "aa", 'Lâv');
    $mail->addReplyTo( "aa", 'Lâv');
    $mail->addAddress($email, $isim_etkinlik_katilimcilar);
    $mail->ContentType = 'text/calendar';

    $mail->Subject = "Oluşturulan Etkinlik";



    //$mail->addCustomHeader('MIME-version',"1.0");
    $mail->addCustomHeader('Content-type',"text/calendar; method=REQUEST;");
    $mail->CharSet = 'iso-8859-9';
    //$mail->addCustomHeader('Content-Transfer-Encoding',"7bit");
    //$mail->addCustomHeader('X-Mailer',"Microsoft Office Outlook 12.0");
    //$mail->addCustomHeader("Content-class: urn:content-classes:calendarmessage");





    $ical = "BEGIN:VCALENDAR\r\n";
    $ical .= "VERSION:2.0\r\n";
    $ical .= "PRODID:-//YourCassavaLtd//EateriesDept//EN\r\n";
    $ical .= "METHOD:REQUEST\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= "ORGANIZER;SENT-BY=\"MAILTO:'$email'\":MAILTO:'$email'\r\n";
    $ical .= "ATTENDEE;CN= $etkinligi_yapan_mail;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT;PARTSTAT=ACCEPTED;RSVP=TRUE:mailto: $etkinligi_yapan_mail\r\n";
    $ical .= "UID:".strtoupper(md5($event_id))."-kaserver.com\r\n";
    $ical .= "SEQUENCE:".$sequence."\r\n";
    $ical .= "STATUS:".$status."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTSTAMPTZID=Africa/Nairobi:".date('Ymd').'T'.date('His')."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTSTART:".$start."T".$start_time."\r\n";
    $ical .= "DTEND:".$end."T".$end_time."\r\n";
    $ical .= "LOCATION:".$venue."\r\n";
    $ical .= "SUMMARY:".$summary."\r\n";
    //$ical .= "DESCRIPTION:".$meeting_des."\r\n";
    $ical .= "BEGIN:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "TRIGGER:-PT15M\r\n";
    $ical .= "ACTION:DISPLAY\r\n";
    $ical .= "DESCRIPTION:Reminder\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VALARM\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VEVENT\r\n";
    $ical .= "END:VCALENDAR\r\n";

    $mail->Body = $ical;

    //send the message, check for errors
    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
        return false;
    } else {
        echo "Message sent!";
        return true;
    }}
    ?>
```

Comment: $mail->MsgHTML($ical);     //try these

Comment: it printed  the codes directly@VishnuBhadoriya

Comment: Have you not looked at PHPMailer's built-in iCal support?

Comment: off topic, but note that you should use the long form PHP tags -- ie `<?php` rather than `<?` to start your code, because the short form tags are deprecated.

Comment: Is there any resource? I searched a lot but i dont what you are saying about @Synchro

Comment: I used <?php thx @Simba

Comment: I don't have an answer for you (my iCal work was too long ago; I don't remember it well enough to give an answer), but here are a few links that might help: https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/175, https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/issues/47, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12726735/icalendar-and-phpmailer-php

Answer (score -1):

You need to put `$mail->IsHTML(true);` after the `$mail->Body = $ical;`